# So i have created a discord poll bot. How do i make it so specific role can use the bot? (discord.js)

Tags: javascript, discord.js

does someone know a code? This is the poll bot code so where would i need to add the code also? If anyone knows please tell me the code so i can understand it and where to put it

````
const bot = new Discord.Client();

const token = "bot token here";

const PREFIX = "T!";

bot.on('ready', () =>{
    console.log("who has woken the almighty one");
});

bot.on('message', message => {
    let args = message.content.substring(PREFIX.length).split(" ");

    switch(args[0]){

        case "poll":
            const Embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()

             .setColor(0xFFC300)
             .setTitle("Start a poll")
             .setDescription("T!poll to start a poll");

             if(!args[1]){
                 message.channel.send(Embed);

             }
            let msgArgs = args.slice(1).join(" ");

            message.channel.send(msgArgs).then(messageReaction => {
                messageReaction.react("")
                messageReaction.react("")
                message.delete({timeout: 3000, reason: "Poll"});
            });
        break;
    }

});

bot.login(token);```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i understand correctly, you want the command to only work if the user has a specific role?

If so you can use:

```
if(message.member.roles.find(r => r.name === "role")){
  message.channel.send("You can use this command!")
} else {
  message.channel.send("You cannot use this command")
}
```

where `"role"` in `r.name === "role"` is the name of the role.

Say you wanted only users with a "poll" role to use the command, you could do the following:

```
bot.on('message', message => {
    let args = message.content.substring(PREFIX.length).split(" ");

    switch(args[0]){

        case "poll":
            if(message.member.roles.find(r => r.name === "poll")){
               const Embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
                 .setColor(0xFFC300)
                 .setTitle("Start a poll")
                 .setDescription("T!poll to start a poll");

               if(!args[1]){
                   message.channel.send(Embed);
               }

               let msgArgs = args.slice(1).join(" ");

               message.channel.send(msgArgs).then(messageReaction => {
                 messageReaction.react("")
                 messageReaction.react("")
                 message.delete({timeout: 3000, reason: "Poll"});
               });

            } else {
              message.channel.send("You cannot use this command")
            }
            break;
    }

});
```